# What is CPU min MHz in lscpu output?

Tags: cpu, cpu-frequency, lscpu

There are `CPU MHz`, `CPU max MHz` and `CPU min MHz` in `lscpu` output. What are they mean? Especially the `CPU min MHz`? We can think `CPU max MHz` is maximum CPU frequency and `CPU MHz` as current usage. Why there is a minimum?

From `lscpu` man page:
`Minimum megahertz value for the CPU.`

This explanation is not clear to me. What does the `CPU min MHz` actually mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It’s the slowest speed at which the processor can run, *e.g.* if the CPU doesn’t have much to do (depending on the governor in use) but can’t go to sleep, or if it’s throttled (from overheating, typically). You’ll see the current speed reported by `lscpu` vary between the minimum and maximum values.